# Why can Plesk not use an existing user account?

Tags: plesk

I am using Plesk to administrate my server.

The first thing I want to do is add my domain.

So I click "Add Domain".

Plesk suggests that I use the user account "root".

I go ahead and try to use this.

Now when I want to save my settings, Plesk tells me that "User account root already exists."

Why can Plesk not use an existing account?

[image]

Comment: Rename user to `admin`

Comment: @Justinas You mean I should enter "admin" in that textbox?

Comment: @Justinas When I do that, it says "admin already exists".

Comment: So if you have these users, the why you wish to add them? Add `xXx-administrator-2021-xXx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a new username associated with the newly created webspace/domain.

Comment: Thank you. And why is it related to the Ubuntu accounts? Why can Plesk not use "root" eve

Comment: Because of security reasons.